# What does virtually initialized mean for mapping initialization in Solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

In Solidity documentation it is mentioned that mapping types are **virtually** initialised such that every possible key exists. If this is the case then mapping types would take a huge amount of disk space if the key is long. So I'm actually wondering what "virtually" means in this context.

Thanks.